# How do I upload a file using Fetch and Multer and post form data in the same request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

I am trying to implement a form that can post information to a server and if the user wants, he/she can upload an image with it. However, Every time I use fetch to send them to the server, only the text data is reaching the server whereas the file, comes with the value of an empty object = {}.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
            <form className="contact-form flex container" onSubmit={(e) => this.submitValue(e)} encType="multipart/form-data">
                <div className="contact-form__block flex column">
                    <label htmlFor="name"className="contact-form__label">Texto: </label>
                    <textarea name="text" id="name" className="contact-form__textarea" placeholder="Digite sobre o que quer falar" onChange={(e) => this.handleInputs(e)} value={text}/>
                </div>
                <div className="contact-form__send-buttons flex">
                    <input type="file" name="sampleFile" onChange={this.insertFile}/>
                    <button className="contact-form__submit"> Enviar </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Then I have the *insertFile* function that inserts file info to the state and then *submitFile* function that sends the post request

```
insertFile(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            file: e.target.files[0]
        })
    }

    submitValue(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        })
    }
```

on the back end, I implemented multer like this:

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb){
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

let upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

And now I am trying to retrieve the value on req.file, but nothing gets passed

```
router.post('/register', upload.single('sampleFile'), (req, res) => {
  const { body: {name, subject, text} } = req;
  console.log('RECEIVED: ', req.body) // RECEIVED:  { text: 'test1234', file: {} }
})
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Omit the headers attribute when sending your request and don't stringify the file object

```js
 submitValue(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: this.state.file
        })
    }
```

Comment: if I dont stringify the object then the `text` input is also not passed. I did what you said and still I couldn't get the file.